# Why spark streaming receive data from kafka use more memory than <executorMemory * executorCount + driverMemory>?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I submitted a Spark Streaming application to a YARN cluster with client mode as follows:

```
./spark-submit \
--jars $JARS \
--class $APPCLS \
--master yarn-client \
--driver-memory 64m \
--executor-memory 64m \
--conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=false \
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false  \
--num-executors 6 \
/data/apps/app.jar
```

**executorMemory * executorCount + driverMemory = 64m*6 + 64m = 448m**,

But the application actually used ***3968mb***. Why did it happen and how can I reduce the memory use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are the Spark configuration parameters `spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead` and `spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead` which default to 384 MB in your case ([docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html#configuration)).

Then there is the fact that YARN has a memory allocation granularity (`yarn.scheduler.increment-allocation-mb`) which defaults to 512 MB. So everything is rounded up to a multiple of that.

Also there is a minimum allocation size (`yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb`) that defaults to 1 GB. It's either been set lower in your case or you are not correctly looking at the memory allocation.

---

All this overhead should be negligible compared to your memory use. You should set `--executor-memory` to 20 GB or more. Why are you trying to configure a ridiculously low amount of memory?

Comment: Thank you for so detailed description. In my case, executor only need to process 5 seconds's data. So I want to reduce memory used.